# first-letter makes Chrome highlight in the wrong place

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

When I use this CSScode to style the first letter of my text something weird happens in Chrome:

```css
main p::first-letter {
  font-size: 300%;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <p>
    This is some sample text
  </p>
</main>
```

When I now for example highlight the word 'is', the letters 'pl' of the word 'sample' get highlighted instead. You can test this here: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d0g54131/)

To make it more clear, this is what happens:

[image: demonstration]

As you can see, the highlighted text is in the wrong place.

Is this my mistake or is this a bug in Chrome? How do I fix it?

Comment: In the text `This is some sample text` the first `T` is highlighted. its working fine as intended. Im also on Chrome

Comment: Yeah i agree with @Sandeep...what is your error

Comment: I mean when you click and drag on some text, it turns blue, but in the code it turns blue in the wrong place, should a say select instead of highlight?

Comment: It's not specific for the 300% btw, if you set the first letter size to 100% the same bug appears.

Comment: Just tested on SO App. Same thing happens. Quick fix: wrap first letter with span tag and set spans in specific p's to 300%

Comment: no @timo this is not the same question, I added the gif to make it more clear

Comment: It is exactly the same question and the answer: "This is a bug in Chrome/ium/WebKit: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17528 " applies here as well.

Comment: @timo: No, it's completely different. I marked that question as a duplicate of another, so I can tell you with confidence that that is not the same question. I picked a better duplicate.

Comment: No @timo it's really not, please take a look at my edit (the gif I added) My question is not about selecting the first letter, it is about the fact that chrome selects in the wrong place.

Comment: My bad, I thought your question was about both these problems. Zagonine's answers seems to adress that.

Comment: @timo: Questions about different issues with ::first-letter aren't duplicates of one another just because all of them can be answered with "::first-letter is horribly broken on every browser."

Answer (score 4):

I found why this is doing this. 
It's because of the "return" after the `<p>`.

So for prevent this behavior you have to write the balise `<p>` and his content in one line, like this :

```
<p>This is some sample text</p>
```

And not this way

```
<p>
    This is some sample text
</p>
```

I haven't find an another solution... Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this, at least it gives a work around :)

Answer (score 0):

Best Code for Every Browser will sported this code

```
<main>
<p>
   <span>T</span>his is some sample text
</p>
```

```
main p span{
font-size: 300%;
```

}

Comment: The span should be around the T if you want the same effect as OP